# JSON data in JavaFx tableview

Tags: javafx-2, tableview, javafx, fxml

I am developing application in javaFX .I want to **show json response in the tableview**.
I am not gettting how to do it

My files are as follows:

projects.fxml

```
<TableView fx:id="mytableTableView" layoutX="384.0" layoutY="54.0" prefHeight="210.0"     prefWidth="202.0" tableMenuButtonVisible="true">
  <columns>
    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="ID" fx:id="idColumn" />
    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Name" fx:id="nameColumn" />
    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Identifier" fx:id="identifierColumn" />
    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Description" fx:id="descriptionColumn" />
    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="CreatedOn" fx:id="created_onColumn" />
  </columns>
</TableView>
```

project controller

```
@FXML
TableView<ProjectProperties> mytableTableView;
@FXML TableColumn<ProjectProperties,Integer> idColumn;
@FXML TableColumn<ProjectProperties,String> nameColumn;
@FXML TableColumn<ProjectProperties,String> identifierColumn;
@FXML TableColumn<ProjectProperties,String> descriptionColumn;
@FXML TableColumn<ProjectProperties,String> created_onColumn;


 public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
   {
 String responseJSON = HttpManager.getData(url, null);

  }
```

I get json response in `responseJSON` that I want to show in the table view.

I am not getting how to bind the json to the table view .

It is possible for me to convert json to the array.

But the `setItems()` method of tableview require the ObservableList .

So any suggesstions and example will be greately appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the DataFx project which have method to feed your dataview with JSON :
http://www.javafxdata.org/content/data-sources/

Another source using DataFx with Rest remote source : 
http://fxapps.blogspot.fr/2012/04/fetching-rest-data-sources-with-datafx.html

Answer (score 1):

```
It is possible for me to convert json to the array.

But the setItems() method of tableview require the ObservableList .
```

then just create ObservaleLIst from that array and set to Table View

Sample Code :

```
ObservableList data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(array);

mytableTableView.setItems(data);
```

Comment: You are right but json contains columnname:value    and tableview requires columnname:"name"

Comment: data should be only values , parse u r data to get ProjectProperties[] and then set it